How to set aws lambda runtime to a specific ARN?
I need to set my aws lambda function runtime to a specific runtime , I managed to get the desired ARN from the logs , however it is not working ,
I tried below cli command :
 aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name function_name_xxxx --runtime arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:b475b23763329123d9e6f79f51886d0e1054f727f5b90ec945fcb2a3ec09afdd
I got below error :
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UpdateFunctionConfiguration operation: Value arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:b475b23763329123d9e6f79f51886d0e1054f727f5b90ec945fcb2a3ec09afdd at 'runtime' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [nodejs20.x, provided.al2023, python3.12, java17, nodejs16.x, dotnet8, python3.10, java11, python3.11, dotnet6, java21, nodejs18.x, provided.al2, ruby3.3, java8.al2, ruby3.2, python3.8, python3.9] or be a valid ARN

I tried adding aws account id to the ARN although it was not originally in the logged ARN and still same issue
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name function_name_xxxx --runtime arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account_id_xxxxxx:runtime:b475b23763329123d9e6f79f51886d0e1054f727f5b90ec945fcb2a3ec09afdd
same error resulted as below
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UpdateFunctionConfiguration operation: Value arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account_id_xxxxxx:runtime:b475b23763329123d9e6f79f51886d0e1054f727f5b90ec945fcb2a3ec09afdd at 'runtime' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [nodejs20.x, provided.al2023, python3.12, java17, nodejs16.x, dotnet8, python3.10, java11, python3.11, dotnet6, java21, nodejs18.x, provided.al2, ruby3.3, java8.al2, ruby3.2, python3.8, python3.9] or be a valid ARN

note that I also tried the ARN that is achieved by get-function-configuration cli command under RuntimeVersionConfig.RuntimeVersionArn

You should follow e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-walkthrough.html - afaik custom runtimes are "just" layers.

I am not willing to use a custom runtime , I want to roll back to a previous runtime with specific ARN , the error message states that ARN is an accepted value for runtime but it fails to update the function

Ah, you want to use an AWS provided but outdated / superseded runtime?!

I think you need https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/api/API_PutRuntimeManagementConfig.html then to specify a Manual runtime management and set the runtime arn, see e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-update.html#runtime-management-rollback-manual for a bit more information

Thanks, the answer was in the docs shared by you, which is below command , do you like to post an answer with that ?
aws lambda put-runtime-management-config --function-name arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxx_acount_id_xxx:function:xxx_my_function_name --update-runtime-on Manual --runtime-version-arn arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:0cdcfbdefbc5e7d3343f73c2e2dd3cba17d61dea0686b404502a0c9ce83931b9

Nah, I don't post answers anymore, just happy to help.

The answer is the below command extracted form the docs shared by luk2302
aws lambda put-runtime-management-config --function-name arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxx_acount_id_xxx:function:xxx_my_function_name --update-runtime-on Manual --runtime-version-arn arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:0cdcfbdefbc5e7d3343f73c2e2dd3cba17d61dea0686b404502a0c9ce83931b9

